# printWriter in Java

Tags: java, printwriter

I have a question regarding to printWriter, please see code below:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

while (n.hasNext()) {
    String str = n.next();
    if (str.equals("m")) {
        break;
    } else {
        out.printf("%s", str);
        out.print(" ");
    }   
}
n.close();
// out.close();
System.out.println("input is successful");
```

When I input something by keyboard, it output on screen what i input, but it did not process the rest of the program, which meant it did not print "input is successful", however, when I delete the command of out.close(); it kept running the rest program, so I want to ask what does out.close() mean? I thought it just means to stop writing for output, I guess it has something to do with the parameter I put in the new PrintWriter(...)

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close())?

Comment: Because the loop don't have any terminate point to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrintWriter.close()` will also close the underlying stream, i.e. `System.out`. This effectively means that any subsequent outputs to `System.out` will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you Steinar, does it mean the close() method terminate the content which I put in to the printwritter bracket-->new printwriter(...), so if I put a file into the bracket, the close() will terminate the output in this file, right?

Comment: Yes, the file stream will also be closed.